# Visual Studio 2012 Debugging - Strange scripts (fs.js and l.js)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, malware

I was trying to debug my site on Visual Studio 2012 and, all of a sudden, I noticed that the website was behaving strangely slower.

I checked the network tab on my browser (IE10) and I saw that the website was downloading very strange scripts like fs.js and l.js. Moreover, the scripts are being downloading repeatedly from different urls. See the image below:

[image]

Next, I went to visual studio and saw this:

[image]

These scripts (that I don't recognize, I do not use or import then anywhere) are being downloaded to the infinity, crashing my website.

Any idea about what this can be? This only seems to happen running the site on local host.

Comment: Image is too small: can't read the text.

Comment: Okay, was able to zoom and see it. Looks related to the shpr.co malware. Not clear yet whether it infected your local machine or your server, but regardless the result is that your site is now serving unwanted material. Get rid of those.